# Index value of First candle of the day in pine

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to write a for loop in pine which satrts from latest completed candle (index value i=0) and ends at days first candle (candle timeframe is as selected on chart) then what condition should i impose on value of i, so that it does not go into previous day candles. Please reply.

I couldnt find a way to terminate i at first candle of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Use `timeframe.change()` to figure out if it is a new day and use a `var` variable to store the bar index.

```
is_new_day = timeframe.change("D")

var first_candle_idx = bar_index

first_candle_idx := is_new_day ? bar_index : first_candle_idx
```